# C# File.exists returns false

Tags: c#, onedrive

I have a program that opens a database, the path to that database is this:

```
private static string strDefaultDB2 = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\OneDrive\TIME FILE\MyName\TimeFile.accdb";
```

All computers I have tried this one were able to access it fine except one, it also has access to OneDrive but when I run the code the file doesn't exist... If I enter the path generated by the code which is something like this:

```
C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\TIME FILE\MyName\TimeFile.accdb
```

In explorer, it opens up the database right away. I'm not sure why it can't find the database on this one machine... I also tried running it as admin but that didn't change anything

This is the code that executes:

```
 if (!System.IO.File.Exists(doesFileExist))
            {

                Polaris.Polaris.log("The Path " + doesFileExist + " Does Not Exist!");

                runWindowDB();


            }
```

If I try to do a rename on the file it throws an exception: "Could not find file [path]"

And If I try to open the database: "[path] is not a valid path"

I don't get it because this path has whitespace on every pc and the only thing that changes is the username. Explorer opens the file so the path is correct.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What exception and innerexception are you getting exactly? Could the user have been renamed and have his username not be the same as his folder name? Does the user running the program have the rights to open the file? What code is throwing exactly? You only show us how you create the string to the path, not how you open it after, post that, post the exact exception you get (all of it, the full message, the exception type etc).

Comment: Is it possible that the file has the "hidden" attribute?

Comment: You should use Path.Combine if your path has whitespaces

Comment: @chris579 you should prefer Path.Combine when building paths with strings, having whitespace or not is irrelevant.

Comment: That specific user has onedrive installed/enabled/a valid account?

Comment: @rene yes that user is the original owner of that onedrive folder and has access to the file

Comment: Give this a try `Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),
    @"\OneDrive\TIME FILE\MyName\TimeFile.accdb")` instead of your path fiddling but I don't have high hopes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an exception? Can you read/write this file?
You have a whitespace in the string I don't think that is good anyway.

From the official documentation [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

> If path describes a directory, this method returns false. Trailing
>   spaces are removed from the path parameter before determining if the
>   file exists.
>
> The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to
>   determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations
>   that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid
>   characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if
>   the caller does not have permission to read the file.

Comment: Whitespace **IN** in a path isn't an issue since FAT32, introduced in 1996.

Answer (score 0):

Hard code another users username that you know works, try it from this machine, msdn mentions it will return false if there are invalid characters in the string or if the path is determined to be a folder, there might be some odd encoding going on or virus scanner intercepting the io. If that fails try getting the user to log onto another box that works and if the file is then recognized it must the environment on that users original box.